# Hadoop MR job - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVParser

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, opencsv

Oozie workflow triggers a Hadoop Map Reduce job's Java class. I have added opencsv-2.3.jar and commons-lang-3-3.1 jar dependencies in my Eclipse project. The project builds successfully, however when moved it on Hadoop cluster I get an ClassNotFoundError even though my project contains jar.

Since this is a working existing legacy system, I do not wish to change the environment dependencies. Hence, i tried different combinations by adding libraries to classpath without success.

Tried: [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader - Upload File Vaadin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910553/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-au-com-bytecode-opencsv-csvreader-upload-file)

Checked with a MR client maven dependency - org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-common:2.6.0-cdh5.4.2.

The legacy jar in production env runs fine, but my project's compiled jar throws errors as follows:

oozie syslog:

```
INFO [uber-SubtaskRunner] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_123213123123_35305
INFO [communication thread] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1548794054671_35304_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
INFO [uber-SubtaskRunner] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job: Job job_123213123123_35305 running in uber mode : false
INFO [uber-SubtaskRunner] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
INFO [uber-SubtaskRunner] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_123213123123_35305_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
```

oozie stderr:

```
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVParser
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

Please suggest if I am missing anything and what I can try.[image]

Answer (score 0):

opencsv-2.3.jar library was added from Eclipse Build Path as an external jar. I had to use mvn clean and build it. Finally, used "*jar-with-dependencies.jar" from the target folder which fixed the issue.